# Reasons of Invalid property 'dao' of bean class

Tags: java, spring, dao

In applicationContext_dao I got bean classNameDao, and now I am trying to create a BUS layer and add to applicationContext_bus two beans.

```
<bean id="classNameValidator" class="cz.mikros.w4.model.bus.validator.ClassNameValidator">
        <property name="dao" ref="classNameDao" />
</bean>

<bean id="classNameBus" class="cz.mikros.w4.model.bus.impl.ClassNameBusImpl">
    <property name="dao" ref="classNameDao" />
    <property name="validator" ref="classNameValidator" />
</bean>
```

problem is

> *Caused by: org.springframework.beans.NotWritablePropertyException: Invalid property 'dao' of bean class [path.model.bus.validator.ClassNameValidator]: Bean property 'dao' is not writable or has an invalid setter method. Does the parameter type of the setter match the return type of the getter?*

Can you navigate me where can be the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if your `path.model.bus.validator.ClassNameValidator` has public setter method on dao. It should be called `public void setDao(DAO dao)`

Comment: Yes, I got this method

Comment: Ok, you was right I got problem in getter, thanks a lot